# Update LastWriteTime without closing the FileStream

Tags: powershell, streamwriter

I am successfully using StreamWriter to incrementally write a log file, and to ensure real time logging I have tried both AutoFlush as well as the Flush() method. Both work, the log file updates in real time. However, the LastModified data isn't changed until a Close. And a separate process I want to do is copy that log to a network location for real time monitoring, but only on changes. So I need to see the LastWriteTime to know when to Copy.
I could I guess recreate the StreamWriter for each write, so I can also close right after, but that seems really inefficient. Is there some way to get the LastWriteTime to update without closing the stream?

EDIT: Interestingly, file SIZE is updated without a close, so the Length property gives me the trigger for an update. I love Microsoft consistency. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have the complete file path available, you could try the following:

```
$filePath = "C:\the\path\for\your\streamwrite\file.txt"
$fileReference = (Dir $filePath)
$fileReference.LastWriteTime = Get-Date
```

It changes the file info immediately.

Comment: Interesting. Conceptually I don't quiet understand the concept of Get-ChildItem on a file, but interesting to know that works when Get-Item doesn't.